# Applying function if column fits requirements

Tags: r, subset, apply

I may be thinking too hard about this, or not thinking hard enough. Can't decide which. I'm using the package (BBMM) to construct movement models for wildlife using x,y coordinates and time lag (as is required by the function brownian.bridge() within BBMM).

My issue is that the function works on one individual at a time. I have a data frame (sheep) with 20+ individuals designated by an ID (CollarSerialNumber) as shown below:

> sheep

```
       CollarSerialNumber  EASTING NORTHING Time.lag
1                  37434 824635.2  2186799        0
2                  37434 824640.5  2186798      360
3                  37434 824644.8  2186791      360
4                  37434 824668.9  2186739      360
5                  37434 824637.6  2186786      360
6                  37435 824640.7  2186787      360
7                  37435 824648.1  2186784      360
8                  37435 824653.3  2186789      360
9                  37435 824644.7  2186797      360
10                 37435 824640.5  2186800      360
11                 37436 824637.5  2186791      360
12                 37436 824637.5  2186791      360
13                 37436 824647.8  2186800      360
14                 37436 824644.7  2186796      360
15                 37436 824637.6  2186787      360
16....
```

The function looks like this:

```
brownian.bridge(x, y, time.lag, location.error, cell.size)
```

x, y, and time.lag are supplied by the data frame, and the other two are manually input. It looks like this:

```
BBMMID=brownian.bridge(x=sheep$Easting, y=sheep$Northing, 
                       time.lag=sheep$Time.lag[-1], 
                       location.error=20, cell.size=30)
```

The function works fine when the data frame includes just one ID. I have been taking my entire csv file and splitting it into 20+ separate csv files based on the ID (one for 37434, 37435, etc.) and this works fine. The process, however, is tedious and time consuming. I'm looking for a way to apply functions over a set of rows if the column fits a certain requirement.

For example, if I want to apply this function to JUST 37434 within the whole data frame without needing to break things up in excel (I'm not very experienced with code, if you can't already tell!) how would I go about it? Would this be an if-then issue? An apply function? Subsetting?

Comment: The `apply` function would seem to be the best option. You can wrap the `brownian.bridge` in a custom function. This function would take the data frame as well as whatever you want to subset it by.

Comment: the case is not the same in data and example, is it a mistake in the post or in your code ?

Comment: Where in that function is *CollarSerialNumber* being passed into it? Or in the other words, how do you know it only works for one ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider `by` to output a list of `brownian.bridge` outputs equal to distinct number of *CollarSerialNumber*. As info, `?by` slices your dataframe by selected factor(s) and passes a dataframe filtered to each factor value into its *FUN* call:

```
objList <- by(sheep, sheep$collarSerialNumber, FUN=function(df) 
              brownian.bridge(x=df$Easting, y=df$Northing, 
                              time.lag=df$Time.lag[-1], 
                              location.error=20, cell.size=30))
```

To access first object in objList use either number or name reference:

```
objList[[1]]

objList$`37434`
```

Comment: by() seems to be the function I was looking for, thank you!

Comment: So did the solution work? There's a tick mark to side to tell us so.

Comment: It did, thank you. This was the first question I've ever asked so I'm not familiar with the procedure. I appreciate the expertise!

Comment: Great to hear! Glad I could help. Happy coding.